# How to remove "create" option from Many2many field while keeping "add an item" in odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

I have create a Many2Many field and I want to hide/remove create option which is showing when we are clicking on Add an item. I have added screenshot for reference. [Link for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLnoZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Options

**no_create - remove the “Create” button.**

**no_quick_create - remove the Create and edit... option**

Example

```
<field name="field_name" options="{'no_create': True}"/>
```

for more information you can use this link

[Form widgets for many2many fields in Odoo](http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/form-widgets-many2many-fields-options-odoo.html)